Angular: "Injector has already been destroyed."
Angular app with a reactive form suddenly started reporting this error:

RuntimeError: NG0205: Injector has already been destroyed.

How do I find the culprit?

In my particular case, a form with asyncValidators was to blame: Angular did not properly unsubscribe from a hot observable that used rxjs.share().
Use rx.takeUntil() to unsubscribe in time (thanks @ilya.chepurnoy):
import * as rx from 'rxjs';

class myComponent {
  /** The form: select the filling device
   */
  form = new FormGroup({
    field: new FormControl<number>(0, {
        asyncValidators: [
            (control: AbstractControl): rx.Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => 
              this.observable$.pipe(
                rx.take(1),  // complete observable immediately
                //... validation ... //
                rx.takeUntil(this.destroyed$), // the solution
            ),
    ]}),
  });


  // Observable that completes when the component is destroyed
  private destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new rx.ReplaySubject(1);

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}

Alternatively, use untilDestroyed(this) from ngneat/until-destroy.

do we need untilDestroyed from ngneat, or simple takeUntil would do just fine ?

@ilya.chepurnoy thank you! Answer changed, now uses destroy$ :)

More context would help.
Does this happen while trying to run something inside the onDestroy hook?
If you're using SSR in your angular app, check the server routes: app.config.server.ts, you might be using a client side library that is not compatible with SSR or does not play well with HMR.
You can try switching the component's route to be Client rendered(RenderMode.Client). If that's not an option, put the offending block inside the afterRender or afterNextRender hook.
  ...
  private readonly destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  constructor(...) {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      ... your on init block
      // onDestroy hook
      this.destroyRef.onDestroy(() => {
        ...
        // on destroy block
      });
    });
  }

